# Select box to change url

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, sorting

I want to use a select to change the query on the end of a url to change it's sort options. e.g:

```
<select id="sort"> 
    <option value="?order_by=date">Recent</option> 
    <option value="?order_by=random">Popular</option>
    <option value="?order_by=random">Random</option> 
    <option value="">Staff Picks</option>
</select>
```

so for example by default a list of posts will be shown by date and then if a user chooses an option it will reload the page with the query string on the end of the URL. If possible looking to use jQuery to achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attach a handler to the change event for the select box that adds the value of the selected option to the current window location with everything after the ? snipped off:

```
$('#sort').change(function(e){
    var locAppend = $(this).find('option:selected').val(),
        locSnip   = window.location.href.split('?')[0];

    window.location.href = locSnip + locAppend;
});
```

[Here's an example ࢐](http://jsfiddle.net/VajkR/) (it doesn't redirect, but you get the idea...)

---

To have the appropriate value selected on page load, you can run the following function before you bind the change handler:

```
function selectCurSort() {
    var match = window.location.href.split('?')[1];
    $('#sort').find('option[value$="'+match+'"]').attr('selected',true);
}
selectCurSort();
```

Comment: How do I make it so the select box has the selected value in relation to the query? So if I choose Popular it will remain as that on the postback?

Comment: What do you mean by running the function BEFORE the bind? Do I just put the function in front of the other code?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it will probably trigger the change handler and be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: The $ needs removing after option[value as this throws an unrecognized expression error.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
$("#sort").change(function(){
  window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that set the *entire URL* to `?order_by=date` (for example)? Wouldn't `window.location += $(this).val();` work slightly more appropriately? (Appending *to* the URL, not *replacing* it.)

Comment: @David Although I don't have specs to back me up, but from experience it will work just fine.

Comment: @David, I believe it is smart enough to know if you mean another domain or just a page or querystring.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure why you aren't just using something like:

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="query" value="..." />

    <select id="sort" name="order_by">
        <option value="date">Recent</option>
        <option value="popular">Popular</option>
        <option value="random">Random</option>
        <option value="staff">Staff Picks</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Sort" />
</form>
```

And, for the JS, if any, just:

```
$('#sort').change(function() {
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
```

Then, you don't require anyone to have JavaScript enabled.

Comment: "Then, you don't require anyone to have JavaScript enabled."? Then ... what's your second snippet of code?

Comment: @Haochi — It's *optional* Javascript.  If JS is blocked, the user can still click the "Sort" button.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
onchange="if (this.value && /^\?/.test(this.value)) location = location.path + this.value"
```

to your `<select>`.

You might want to put a blank option at the top too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
   $("#sort").change(function() {
     var myVal = $(this).val();
     window.location = "www.mywebsite.com/"+ myVal;
   });
   var qs = window.location.pathname;
   $("#sort option").each(function() {
       if(qs.contains($(this).val()))
        $(this).addAttr("selected","selected");
    });
});
```

Try that.

Comment: How do I make it so the select box has the selected value in relation to the query? So if I choose Popular it will remain as that on the postback?